# Change Excel default Icon (on Windows 7)

Tags: icons, shortcut-file

I have searched if this issue was previously asked, but it seems that other questions are quite similar, but not exactly.

What I want to do is simple : 
-change Excel default Icon. (when navigating in folders & desktop of my user session)

For your information : I use Windows 7.

Anyone can help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Well, first question is what system are you using? Mac / Windows and then which version...

Comment: Are you asking how to do this within a computer program? Because if you are asking only how to change a specific computer system, this question is off-topic for this site, and should be better asked at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @SolarMike I use Windows.

Comment: @MYPE- then you should edit your question appropriately... Not including pertinent information does not help those that may be prepared to help you.

Comment: ok @SolarMike, thanks, I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Reading the help files will help prevent downvotes (was not me BTW), here is a link to one : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is the question more clear now ? @SolarMike

Comment: I noticed your edit - well done +1 from me,.

Comment: By the looks of it you can only do it with shortcuts as @Lonolian has tried to point out - right-click your file icon and select `Send to desktop (create shortcut)`.  The shortcut that appears on the desktop has the "shortcut" tab that Lonolian mentions.  It seems you can't change the icon for a file type without downloading some software to do it unless you're XP or earlier. [How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13631/customize-your-icons-in-windows-7-and-vista/)

Comment: > OK @DarrenBartrup-Cook ok it was the missing information ! It works perfectly. Thanks to you, and to Lonolian therefore.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

right click, properties, shortcut, change Icon, you can see that the icon set is here:

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\Windows\Installer{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe

Here you can select any other Icon, but to change the defult, I am pretty sure you need to replace the xlicons.exe file.

Comment: Right click on what?

Comment: Right click on what? >On the icon of Excel    Does that work on a Mac? > No clue, never had Apple products.

Comment: @Lonolian thank you for the answer. I cannot see "Shortcut" in the Properties Menu. Do you know why ? (I use Windows 7)

Comment: Thank you @Lonolian, it works ! I just needed to know that a shortcut must be made first, as DarrenBartrup-Cook said. Thank you.